# Why we create RDD to save data in Hbase? Is there any other way save data in Hbase?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase

I am totally new in Bigdata, Hadoop and Spark. I am from Java background.

So I am trying to understand why people always created RDD to save the dataset in HBASE. Could anyone tell me in details for this.

Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: if you are okay with answer pls vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark everything and anything boils down to RDD. i.e. including data frame.
AFAIK, there is no other option for Spark and hbase,  If you use spark as distributed framework achieves its goal through RDD which are

- Immutable
- Partitioned
- Fault tolerant
- Created by coarse grained operations
- Lazily evaluated
- Can be persisted

Immutability and partitioning
RDDs composed of collection of records which are partitioned. Partition is basic unit of parallelism in a RDD, and each partition is one logical division of data which is immutable and created through some transformations on existing partitions.Immutability helps to achieve consistency in computations.

Users can define their own criteria for partitioning based on keys on which they want to join multiple datasets if needed.

Coarse grained operations (transformations and actions)
Coarse grained operations are operations which are applied to all elements in datasets. For example – a map, or filter or groupBy operation which will be performed on all elements in a partition of RDD.

Transformations and actions

RDDs can only be created by reading data from a stable storage such as HDFS/Hbase or by transformations on existing RDDs. All computations on RDDs are either transformations or actions.
[image]

Fault Tolerance

Since RDDs are created over a set of transformations , it logs those transformations, rather than actual data.Graph of these transformations to produce one RDD is called as Lineage Graph.

Scala

```
firstRDD=spark.textFile("hdfs://...")
secondRDD=firstRDD.filter(someFunction);
thirdRDD = secondRDD.map(someFunction);
result = thirdRDD.count()
```

[image]

Lazy evaluations
Spark computes RDDs lazily the first time they are used in an action, so that it can pipeline transformations. So , in above example RDD will be evaluated only when count() action is invoked.

Persistence
Users can indicate which RDDs they will reuse and choose a storage strategy for them (e.g., in-memory storage or on Disk etc.)

These properties of RDDs make them useful for fast computations.

Please see [Source : what is RDD and Why we need it](http://saurzcode.in/2015/10/what-is-rdd-in-spark-and-why-do-we-need-it/)